# PHP Debugger Live Preview

Tags: php, debugging, live

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) and [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com/) are two examples of live debuggers. I'm looking for something like this, but for PHP.

Closest I came across were the two sites below, but not exactly what I'm looking for:

- http://codepad.viper-7.com/
- http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php

Does anyone know of a php debugger with a live keyup sort of feature?

**Update**: Here's some links to live php debuggers if anyone else is looking:
http://writecodeonline.com/php4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some websites that might suit you:

- [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php)
- [writecodeonline](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)
- [viper-7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/)

Comment: Thank you writecodeonline is exactly what I've been looking for.